# Add time trigger

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

After clicking on "Add time trigger" button in Workflow rules (for time dependent WF)..we have Days/Hours ,  Before/After and Rule trigger Date/ created date/modified date DROP DOWNS.

My question is if we select Before in second drop down..how could it works.
coz in third drop down we need to select one from Rule trigger Date/ created date/modified date among these 3 options.

So, How " before" works

Answer (score 1):

An example use case of before in a time based workflow rule, would be 7 days "Before" the opportunity close date. This would be useful in notifying the opportunity owner that their close date is approaching so they can either adjust the date or make the sale.
See [help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US) article here for additional considerations when using time-based workflow rules.